# opencv-python compatibility with pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

My system has these packages (reported with *pip list*):

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip list

numpy (1.13.1+mkl)
opencv-python (3.3.0)
pip (9.0.1)
setuptools (28.8.0)*
```

Then, when I try to install Pyinstaller, I get this error:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install --index-url=http://pypi.python.org/simple/ --trusted-host pypi.python.org pyinstaller

Collecting pyinstaller
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyinstaller (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyinstaller*
```

Is there not a Pyinstaller version compatible with my installations of Opencv-python (i.e. 3.3.0)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.  Pyinstaller has nothing to do with OpenCV.  It's the Python installation specifications you need to worry about.  That error means that `pip` could not find the desired package.

You can still download it though. For both Python 2.7 and almost all versions of Python-3.  Here's how:

**1)**  Go to [Pyinstaller Download Page](http://www.pyinstaller.org/downloads.html)

**2)**  Download 3.3.1 (the latest stable release)  You are looking for a `tar.gz` file

**3)**  Extract the contents.

**4)**  Once you have the folders with all the files (you will need to extract them) run `python setup.py install`.

**5)**  Wait while it installs.  Your done!